# Gradle: how to stop publish and show error message

Tags: gradle, publish

Gradle: try to stop "publish"

```
tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository) {
    doFirst {
        throw new GradleException('publish is not allowded')
    }

}
```

It seems publish is disabled. but No error message:

```
> Task :publish UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':publish' as it has no actions.

:publish (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

Comment: Looks like you try to stop something, that would not run anyway. Also why would you configure a publish task if you don't want it?

Comment: prohibit user from doing it wrongly. It is configured for publishToMavenLocal.